# Calling this react HOC feels like i could abstract this in another way please advice

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, higher-order-components

I'm a beginner and need advice. I learn Reactjs and created this HOC so I could navigate in the Router V6. My concern is that from my desktop `Navbar` and from the mobile side menu I have links to the same `Dashboard`.

So I create a HOC since it's the same code running in both locations and the HOC now have this code.

**This is the HOC:**

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthUserContext from './context';
import * as ROLES from '../constants/roles';

const WithDashboardNavigate = Component => {
    class WithDashboardBase extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.onDashboard = this.onDashboard.bind(this);
        }

        onDashboard = navigate => {
            const { authUser } = this.props;
            if (authUser) {
                if (authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON)) {
                    navigate('/app/login');
                } else if (authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.USER) || authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ADMIN)) {
                    const view = localStorage.getItem('currentDashBoardView');
                    // Here if user has used nav menu earlier then that last view is loaded
                    if (view) navigate(view);
                    // or default to dash
                    else navigate('/app/dashboard');
                }
            }
        };

        render() {
            return <Component dashboardNavigater={this.onDashboard} {...this.props} />;
        }
    }

    const WithDashboard = () => (
        <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            {authUser => (
                <div>
                    <WithDashboardBase authUser={authUser} />
                </div>
            )}
        </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    );

    return WithDashboard;
};

export default WithDashboardNavigate;
```

**And I use it like this from  `Navbar`:**

```
function SignedInButton(props) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function openDashboard() {
        props.dashboardNavigater(navigate);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button className="button is-large" onClick={openDashboard}>
                <span className="icon is-medium">
                    <i className="fas fa-user" />
                </span>
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WithDashboardNavigate(SignedInButton);
```

**And I use it like this from  `SideMenu`:**

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import WithDashboardNavigate from '../../session/WithDashboardNavigate';

function SideMenu(props) {
    const { close, dashboardNavigater } = props;
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onProfilePageClick = () => {
        if (close) close();
        dashboardNavigater(navigate);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <MenuLinksSpace />
            <MenuLinks>
                <li>
                    <a onClick={onProfilePageClick} role="presentation">
                        <span className="icon is-medium">
                            <i className="fas fa-user" />
                        </span>{' '}
                        Dashboard
                    </a>
                </li>
            </MenuLinks>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My question is I'm I overdoing this? I mean is there an easier way to do this conforming better to React best praxis?

Comment: Its an opinioned based question, my opinion is that if you using function components you don't need to use HOC, it defeats its purpose.

Comment: @DennisVash How do you mean "function components" I still have the same code running at two location? This is not opinion based question it's about how to create good code and help with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally dependent on the requirement and how you design. My opinion is that if you using function components you don't need to mix with class components and bind(this).

**Note:** WithDashboard function you are not passing props if any component passes props that are not passed to WithDashboardBase.

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthUserContext from './context';
import * as ROLES from '../constants/roles';

const WithDashboardNavigate = Component => {
    const WithDashboardBase = (props) => {
       const onDashboard = navigate => {
            const { authUser } = props;
            if (authUser) {
                if (authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON)) {
                    navigate('/app/login');
                } else if (authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.USER) || authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ADMIN)) {
                    const view = localStorage.getItem('currentDashBoardView');
                    // Here if user has used nav menu earlier then that last view is loaded
                    if (view) navigate(view);
                    // or default to dash
                    else navigate('/app/dashboard');
                }
            }
        };

        return <Component dashboardNavigater={onDashboard} {...props} />;
    }

    const WithDashboard = (props) => (   // Pass props from here as well 
        <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            {authUser => (
                <div>
                    <WithDashboardBase authUser={authUser} {...props} />
                </div>
            )}
        </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    );

    return WithDashboard;
};

export default WithDashboardNavigate;
```

I have created connect HOC for context API(same as redux). Check this it'll help you understand props pass from parent to child.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management?file=src%2FStore.js

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand this "WithDashboard function you are not passing props if any component passes props that are not passed to WithDashboardBase.". Can you show example?

Comment: Let's take an example `<SignedInButton {someprops}/>`  some props will not pass to the WithDashboardBase component.

Comment: I see so it's like `WithDashboardBase` should only know about the props it needs to know

Comment: Thanks for the bliz I like Redux a lot but have never used React `useReducer` it's a good example you show